# Objective-C and Android

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, android, android-ndk

I've just finished a relatively large project for the Android, and it's left a bitter taste in my mouth with the knowledge that it will never run on one of the most ubiquitous handsets this side of the solar system (the one by that fruity little club).

So, for my next project, I want to write it in a way that makes most of the components easily transportable between the iPhone and Android platforms. The way I'm thinking of doing this is by coding most of it in Objective-C, and then adding the platform-specific parts in more Objective-C and Java respectively. On the Android side, this will require using the the NDK.

My knowledge of C is good, but my knowledge of Objective-C is close to zero, and I have no desire to learn C++. How sane is the approach above, and is there a better one? Is there any way I can code in Java and still reach the un-hacked iPhone market? And how likely is it that the people I know (iPhone users) will have an Android phone by next year?

Comment: @Tom R: some professional game companies that develop application for mobiles use automated porting tool, that translates Java to Obj-C (and to Qualcomm BREW too). The game *Uniwar*, for example, that reached the top ten on the iPhone AppStore and that has been ranked 2nd (or 1st?) best strategy game of 2009 on the iPhone got entirely written in Java and automagically translated to Obj-C. Back in the days the price of the technology was about $2500/quarter per developer, and it worked fine :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380258/crossplatform-iphone-android-code-sharing

Comment: There's also this new tool released by Samsung and Yeecco: http://www.yeecco.com/ecosys/samsung >Built on top of Google Android's native development kit (NDK), Stella SDK is written in pure Objective-C language to bypass interim Java layer. No interpretation of byte codes are necessary at runtime, but machine codes are executed directly on CPU. With a multithreaded architecture, Stella SDK squeezes every bits of system resources to ensure best performance on Android devices.

Comment: There is a new StellaSDK released which will do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16677772/308315

Comment: best way to go nowadays: flutter or react native

Answer (score 24):

Step back and think about what in the end you will logically be able to share.

The UI models are fairly different, the components are different.  In the end what you might be able to share is data object classes, possibly some algorithms.  It's not even like you could realistically end up sharing network code as in the old days because you aren't directly using sockets, you are using HTTP libraries.

So will all of the effort you are putting into this really find a payoff in the end?  It seems to me the end result will be a brittle mess that is hard to update, and is mediocre on both platforms instead of being great on either.

Why are you writing applications?  To make life easier for you, or your users?

Comment: Is is too much to ask for both? :)

Comment: It is not too much to ask... but the universe is not prone to answering such requests very often!

Comment: It might surprise you, but even today, despite some people's best efforts, not all the world fits neatly into an HTTP request.

Comment: @asveikau That's a statement to print out and put up on a wall!

Comment: I totally disagree with this comment. There is a large amount of behavior code that you can share across platform. Using an approach such as TDD would force you to separate the platform code from the business logic. Also there is a wide open market for consistent apps that work equally across handsets.

Comment: In my experience the behavior code is so marginal that it's not worth hamstringing the whole project to just share what amounts to a few pages of psudeocode.  You can keep apps consistent without sharing code, even moreso if you are willing to front a lot of automated tests to ensure consistency.

The reason to keep the code separate is one question:  Do you want your application to be consistent, or great on whatever platform it runs on? You cannot have both.  Apps that run the same across all platforms always have areas they could be improved.

Comment: Some types of apps, especially games, are almost *all* behavior that could be cross-platform and *needs* to be consistent. The UI should then be grafted atop that in a platform-specific implementation.

Comment: But you can define behavior at a meta level (usually in some kind of domain specific language) while having engines to process the behavior that vary by platform.

Answer (score 16):

Others have said basically this, but I'd like to make it more explicit. Your best bet is probably to write:

1. Cross-platform data models & core logic, using:

   - bits of [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) (Obj-C), or
   - [CF-Lite](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/cflite.html) (C), or
   - Whatever you'd like, as long as it's cross-platform :P
2. iPhone-only interface code, using Cocoa Touch (Obj-C)
3. Android-only interface code, however they do it for the Android.

That's as close as you can get; any attempt to write cross-platform *interface* code will undoubtedly result in a mediocre app on both platforms. But making *all the rest* of your code portable and just wrapping a device-specific interface around it is done *all the time* and has been worked great for some iPhone developers.

Comment: Best answer so far. This is very helpful for things like simple games, where a large amount of the code is game logic, and a far smaller amount accounts for rendering and UI.

Comment: I would disagree that CF-Lite is a good cross platform solution.  Basically it's convenient for Mac programmers and no one else.  I'd sooner suggest something like GLIB -- although that is a bit biased towards gtk+ programmers.

Comment: You're unlikely to find something that's convenient to use with both the iPhone code and the Android code; I figure why not choose something like CF-Lite that has toll-free bridging with NS classes? That way, at least ONE of your interfaces will be easy to write. :)

Comment: You can now use the [GNUstep Android toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) to set up a project as described above and use Objective C model code based on Foundation and CoreFoundation in an Android app.

Answer (score 11):

Objective-C without Cocoa is not so useful and won't bring you much closer to haveing a working iPhone codebase. You'd probably be better off writing your core in C with Core Foundation and using either Java or Objective-C for the platform specific parts. Apple has open sourced a large chunk of Core Foundation as CF-Lite, and it's toll-free bridged with Cocoa on OS X (i.e. you can use many CF classes interchangeably with their Cocoa counterparts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I specifically mention Obj-C as the language I'd like to code the core in (as opposed to C/C++) is that it has been recommended to me as being a very good C-based OOP language. How unusable is Obj-C without Cocoa?

Comment: Objective-C looks to me to be a perfectly reasonable language without Cocoa.  Hardly anybody ever uses it without Cocoa, because there are more popular languages on all the non-Mac platforms, but I see no reason not to use it.  It is part of gcc, so it should be available on pretty much any Unix or Linux platform.

Comment: He didn't say Objective-C was *unreasonable* without Cocoa, just not nearly as useful. Imagine Java without any java.* and javax.* class, C without the standard library, C# without .NET, etc. A language may be great, but the corresponding code library is what really adds value for most people. Cocoa dramatically cuts the work that the developer must do to the point that without it, Objective-C is reduced to just a really interesting language. By itself, "interesting" doesn't pay the bills. More specifically, an iPhone app without Cocoa will be rudimentary and difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: Obj-C is a good core language.  If I were using it without Cocoa/GNUstep I think the things I would miss the most are `retain` and `release` from `NSObject`, as well as `NS{Mutable,}{Array,Dictionary}` and all the supporting classes.  But if you wanted to rewrite those and whatever else yourself I guess you'd have a good foundation to work with.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda the key. If you didn't have all those things, you'd have to write them yourself from scratch. I agree that the core language is good. However, without the parts I use every day, it would be just another programming language to me. There are many solid languages that nobody uses. Like Smalltalk, on which Objective-C was based. Plenty of others come to mind, but perhaps that's because I spent a fair chunk of time in academia studying CS. :-)

Comment: Smalltalk and Objective C are both great and should be used, Apple libs or no.

Answer (score 9):

My guess, which has no experience to back it up, is that you probably *could* write Obj-C with Google's NDK somehow, given that GCC exists for ARM, is open source, has an Obj-C compiler and a basic Obj-C runtime (which if it doesn't already probably could be hacked up to work on a new architecture), etc.

That might also be a lot of work for questionable benefit.

And of course "Obj-C" (without the `NS` classes) means something very different than "Cocoa", which is what most people *really* mean when they say "Obj-C".  You might be able to re-use some of GNUstep for some that, but...  Honestly, I doubt it.  Sounds again like a lot of work.

So, yes, I think it is possible.  It's also a lot of work and I don't think it's worth it.

Given what you've said, if I were attempting this, I would be tempted to write as much of your core logic as possible in C, then wrap it with two separate GUIs for each platform.

Comment: This is becoming my new mantra... model (and any services/libraries/shared code) in C, view/controller in the most appropriate platform language / library.

Comment: You’re right that gcc and llvm support Objective-C on Android as well. In addition to the compiler you’ll also need the Objective-C runtime, which exists open-source as [libobjc2](https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2) and works on Android. With this, and using GNUstep as an implementation of the Objective-C frameworks (i.e. Foundation) you can absolutely use Objective-C code on Android. The [GNUstep Android Toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) provides a full setup for this.

Answer (score 2):

Coming at this from a different angle... I know that you said you wanted to try and stick with Java, but if you know C# then you could go with the MonoTouch framework for the iPhone.  Mono is essentially and open source implementation of the .Net stack.  The Mono team is working on bringing Mono to the Android so you could basically write a shared C# library for your business logic and have different Views/Controllers per platform.  This would all be in C# of course and it is a bit more expensive, but it does solve the problem of writing everything in different languages.

I believe it is called [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) on the iPhone and MonoDroid on Android.

Comment: Go with this, and get your store blocked from the AppStore. Apple doesn't want you going this way.  The original question asker apparently already knew that too, and that's why he thought of the "okay, so we'll use Objective C everywhere" idea, which is also unworkable.  Apple's restriction requires that your app be written "originally" in some combination of C, C++,  and Objective C.  Since C libraries are allowed, I don't see why the original asker would care at all about using ObjectiveC anywhere other than iPhone. Thus the question is a bit of an unusual one.

Comment: @Warren P: I know this is an old comment, but for future readers, I'd like to note that this is no longer so. Neither Unity nor Mono have had problems with Apple. Apple's restriction was targeted at Adobe Flash, and that was about it. Rule was also lifted.

Comment: That's correct. Apple has relaxed a LOT since then.  They relaxed not only mono (runtime) and language (other than Objective-C) questions, they also allowed emulators (like C=64) back in, and lots more. My comment was correct when it was written, and could be correct again, in the future, if the winds at Apple shift again.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apportable SDK](http://www.apportable.com/) is an Objective-C approach to write once and deploy to both IOS and Android. It will cross-compile a running IOS Xcode project to an Android SDK.

See [here](http://docs.apportable.com/index.html) for sample apps that run on both platforms in minutes after download.

Comment: While Apportable no longer exists, the [GNUstep Android Toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-android) provides a similar solution to enable using Objective-C on Android using Foundation, CoreFoundation, and libdispatch.

Comment: Still some artifacts from Apportable available on GitHub - https://github.com/apportable/Foundation and https://github.com/apportable

Comment: True, but afaik not the toolchain to enable compilation of Objective-C code on Android.

Comment: Likely has rotted - but https://github.com/phausler/clang

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Android but with the iPhone you can essentially write straight C as long as you wrap it up in Objective-C classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C runtime has not been ported to Android yet. It shouldn't be too much work, but still, without a working knowledge of the language I doubt you'll have an easy time porting it.

What you are trying to do is going to be hard for a generic application, but should be possible for games, if you choose to develop the game in plain C (which is supported by both the Android NDK and the iPhone). You'd have to write up some glue code to pass input events from the Obj-C and Java environments into your C code, but that shouldn't be much of a problem - Objective-C allows you to directly call into your C code and there are plenty of example projects which do exactly this for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself or finished watching the talk yet, but there is a Google Tech Talk on [Developing iPhone Applications using Java](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8nMpi5-P-I) up on YouTube that looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 1):

XMLVM is a project which is capable of translating (some) Android applications to the iPhone. For more infromation, visit http://xmlvm.org/android/

Answer (score 1):

I realize this may be a tad late, but it seems the industry is going in the direction of web apps these days to achieve app portability. That is, embedding a web-browser in your "skeleton native app", and writing javascript, css and html for Android, iOS and the other major smartphone platforms.

There are tools that help you with this. You might want to check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), but there are many more. Note that this approach may not be ideal for real-time/animation-intensive apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a talk from facebook's mobile @ scale conference where two teams (dropbox and orchestra) used similar approaches.  Dropbox used C++ to create libdropbox and Orchestra (mailbox) used Objective-c to create libmailbox.

Again, they wrote their front ends in the platform native language and used their cross platform libs for core logic and data.

Key benefits I took away:  Mailbox went from ios to android in 5 weeks because it was just building UI code.  Dropbox can beta test changes to core functionality that are in the shared library with Android beta deployments were it's easier to do massive deploys at scale for beta builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait until later this year (exact amount of time unknown), Adobe will have AIR for Android and a compiler to iPhone. Thus you can write an app in AIR for the Android and use most of the same code to compile to the iPhone.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/

Even if you can't wait see: http://www.insideria.com/2008/12/actionscript-to-cocoa---protot.html where it explains the similarities between ActionScript and Cocoa.

Also check out: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/ for the AIR version capable of using the touch screen.

So you can soon write once and deploy to Android and iPhone using ActionScript 3.