# Maintaining product for Android + iPhone

Tags: iphone, android, portability

This is a question to all of you out there who develop for both Android and iPhone. How do you maintain support for the two platforms? Specifically, do you

- maintain the two products totally separate from each other?
- create "native" GUIs in Java/ObjC and a "core" library in C/C++?
- write both versions in the same language (e.g. Java) and a third-party tool to generate code for each platform?
- write everything in the same code base and use an even more fancy tool to generate native bindings for each platform?

Comment: This question is very close to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380258/crossplatform-iphone-android-code-sharing , and some of the answers here might also apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045477/android-iphone-single-codebase-cross-development

Comment: Thanks! Yes I saw those questions, but mine was more about what people use in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do create "native" UIs in Java/ObjC and core library is usually in C/C++. That's when the application I am maintaining requires a complex core library.

When the application is simple enough, I just maintain two code bases: Java/ObjC-CocoaTouch.

As far as I know, there are no fancy tools to generate binding for each platform. Maybe [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) will officially support Android at some point and you will be able to do **everything** in C#: Android, iPhone and Windows Phone 7!

Comment: Ah yes, monotouch. I find that project really interesting. Anyway, your approach is also the most appealing to me.