# Developing apps for both iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform

We have customers asking for apps that can run on both iPhone and Android.  I realize this will mean two different development projects, but wonder if anyone has any advice/creative tips on this subject?  e.g. Ways to maximize shared resources?

NOTE: Realize making the app web-based would be most effective way, but looking for advice on cross-development on the native platforms.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380258/crossplatform-iphone-android-code-sharing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045477/android-iphone-single-codebase-cross-development

Comment: Thanks Mayra- these are what I was looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.appcelerator.com/

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

and PhoneGap is good too

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

PhoneGap allows you to develop apps using HTML, CSS and Javascript for a range of mobile devices

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mix of cross-platform HTML5/Javascript for the web-ifiable (in looks and performance) UI parts of the app, and plain ole C (which is both a subset of Objective C, and available in Android through the NDK) for the OpenGL/data/number crunching parts with high performance requirements.  The native UI parts may just have to be redesigned for the native platforms and (re)written twice.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the list of Crossplatform frameworks to use for building hybrid mobile applications :-

1.) Flutter by Google
2.) Ionic
3.) Phonegap with cordova by Adobe
4.) React Native by Facebook
5.) Appcelerator’s Titanium
6.) Meteor.JS
7.) Sencha Touch
8.) JQuery Mobile
9.) NativeScript
10.) Rachet
11.) Mobile Angular UI

Get more useful detailed information of each framework with links on below link : -

https://droidoverflow.blogspot.com/2018/07/top-framework-to-build-hybridcross.html