# Crossplatform development for iPhone & Android

Tags: android, ipad, cross-platform

As far as I can see there doesn't seem to any mature environment for crossplatform development for iPhone & Android slate (but feel free to correct me).

I don't know Ipad, I must admit. Any reason why plain Java wouldn't cut it? (maybe underlying things like database (I am not too concerned with hardware))

I am thinking to try to make everything browser based, although that won't get around the d/b & h/w issues, unless there is JS framework that does so.

Any advice?

Comment: Duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045477/android-iphone-single-codebase-cross-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577790/developing-apps-for-both-iphone-and-android, and many others

Comment: +1 Sorry, don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Download [Worklight](http://www.worklight.com/). With WL you can build cross-platform app using HTML5, JavaScript framework and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 (already mentioned) could be a good option.

Some other options are:

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) - an open-source cross-platform mobile development environment. It basically uses a stylized web-page and Javascript that is compiled into a native app on each platform.

Worklight (http://www.worklight.com)- a commerical product that does the same thing, but it requires a dedicated Worklight server on the backend. Worklight also allows you to target targets additional platforms (with same codebase) such as Yahoo Widgets, iGoogle, Vista gadgets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Java or Flash or supported on iPhone/iPad.  Basic reasoning being cross-platform development leads to a poor second rate user experience.  Do a quick search to see thousands upon thousands of blogs and articles on the topic.

Otherwise look at HTML 5 it gives you a client side database to play with, you don't specify what hardware issues you are implying.

Comment: I am giving you +1 for taking the time to reply, even though I disagree with your statement that "Basic reasoning being cross-platform development leads to a poor second rate user experience".  Maybe if you replace hat "leads" with "can lead". No offence intended, though, so let's not flame. Thanks for the technical info that I can't use Java.  Guess I'll have to look at the current state of HTML 5 support (I think I will be restricted to Chrome as the browser, which I would imagine will have good support).

Comment: I'm paraphrasing Steve Jobs there, one of the excuses behind lack of Flash support on the platforms.